# What do you think about this play?

Tags: poker-strategy

[image]

I am not sure if this was played well or not? WHat do you think, how would you play this hand ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this play is fine, especially since the player you are playing against is short stacked. You just need to keep in mind that if they are going all in preflop, their hand most likely does not have very much implied odds, so they are likely to have a stronger range (AQ+, JJ+). I think I would make the same play some of the time, but it is important to stop and think about what hands you are going up against and maybe think about 4-betting smaller.